# Dynamic value in ng-minlength

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a constant called `Config` which contains a `task.minlength = 3` attribute.

I'm appending the constant in the `$rootScope`:

```
.run(function($rootScope, Config) {
  $rootScope.Config = Config;
})
```

From within a template, I want to set `Config.task.minlength` value into an input's `ng-minlength` directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newTask" placeholder="Write a new task..." required ng-minlength="{{ Config.task.minlength }}">
```

Which gets correctly parsed according to DevTools:

[image]

However, validation doesn't gets triggered:

```
$scope.form.$error['minlength'] // undefined
```

It works fine when I just write `3` instead of interpolating `Config.task.minlength`.

Does the value of `ng-minlength` has to be hardcoded? Is there any workaround?

Comment: remove the expression braces and just use variable

Comment: Still no luck, no error is shown at `$scope.form.$error['minlength']`

Comment: What version are you using? i have no problems... and why not use `$scope.form.$error.minlength` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ngModelController`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) do not [$observe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes) or [$eval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) the value of [`ngMinlength`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput) in any way, therefore It only gets static integer values.

I created my own directive which use `$observe`,
Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/aCaDANaw/1/edit):

```
app.directive('myMinlength',function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,elm,attr,ngModel){

      var minlength = 0;

      var minLengthValidator = function(value){     
        var validity = ngModel.$isEmpty(value) || value.length >= minlength;
        ngModel.$setValidity('minlength',  validity);
        return validity ? value : undefined;
      };

      attr.$observe('myMinlength', function(val){
         minlength = parseInt(val,10);
         minLengthValidator(ngModel.$viewValue);
      });


      ngModel.$parsers.push(minLengthValidator);
      ngModel.$formatters.push(minLengthValidator);
    } 
  };
});
```

Use it like so:

```
<input type="text" name="something" my-minlength="{{config.min}}" ng-model="something">
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, there some syntax errors.

You should set a name for input:

```
<input name="newtask" type="text" ng-model="newTask" placeholder="Write a new task..." required ng-minlength="{{ Config.task.minlength }}">
```

Then, you will catch the error like this:

```
$scope.form.newtask.$error['minlength']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to achieve a dynamic value of `ng-minlength`. Angular will watch $scope values and update accordingly.

See a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tMHQq7YIBlvMw7A60H2e?p=preview

**Controller**

```
function myCtrl (){
   $scope.myMinLength = 5; // could also come from config
}
```

**View:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myString" ng-minlength="myMinLength">
```

The important thing to note, is that the value of `ng-minlength` does not have to be in braces.